# django for-loop only displaying the last iteration

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I'm building a book recommendation Django application. I'm done integrating my machine learning model but the problem is that it gets the data from the csv file i used, not from my database. I have no problem displaying the titles of the recommended books but I would like to let the users view the details page of the said book. With that being said, I need to get the id of the recommended books from my `Book` model.

I'm relatively new to Django so please excuse if my codes are messy.

This is the excerpt from my `views.py`:

```
def s_detail(request, book_id): #student paper detail
    cosine_sim = joblib.load('cosine_sim-v5.pkl') #load the ml model 
    data = pd.read_csv('try.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
    try:
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
        fav = True 
        if book.favorites.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            fav=False
    
        def recommendations(book_id,n, cosine_sim = cosine_sim):
            recommended_books = []
            idx = book_id
            score_series = pd.Series(cosine_sim[idx]).sort_values(ascending = False)
            top_n_indexes = list(score_series.iloc[1:n+1].index)
            for i in top_n_indexes:
                recommended_books.append(list(data.index)[i]) # data.index for book_id column
            return recommended_books

        recommend = recommendations(book_id, 3) 
        for i in recommend: 
            new = Book.objects.filter(id=i) #to get the Book id from the model 
            print(new) #just to check if it's working

    except Book.DoesNotExist: 
        raise Http404("Title does not exist")    
    return render (request, 'books/s_detail.html', {'book':book, 'fav':fav, 'recommend':recommend, 'new':new})
```

in my template:

```
{% for book in new %}
    <div class="card">     
      <img src="/books/media/{{book.book_image}}" alt="bookimage"><br>
        <div class="browse-content">
            <b>Title:</b> <a href="{% url 's_detail' book.id %}"> {{book.book_title}} </a><br>
            <div class="eye">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i> Views
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

the iteration works fine based on the printed output in the terminal

```
[22/Dec/2022 10:27:42] "GET /books/s_browse HTTP/1.1" 200 27157
<QuerySet [<Book: Radioprotective Potential of Leaf Extract of Sapinit (Rubus rosifolius) On the Sperm Count and Sperm Morphology of y-Irradiated Mice (Mus musculus)>]>
<QuerySet [<Book: Analysis of Cytotoxic Activities of Select Plant Extracts against A549 - Lung Adenocarcinoma Cell Line>]>
<QuerySet [<Book: Inventory of Epiphytes on the Walls of Intramuros, Manila>]>
```

but only displays the last iteration in the template

I feel like I need to store the values somewhere but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the `new` variable with a new `QuerySet` of size 1 in your `for` loop. Try replacing the following:

```
recommend = recommendations(book_id, 3) 
for i in recommend: 
    new = Book.objects.filter(id=i) #to get the Book id from the model 
    print(new) #just to check if it's working
```

with this:

```
recommend = recommendations(book_id, 3) 
new = Book.objects.filter(id__in=recommend)
print(new)
```

This will fetch all `Book` instances with an `id` value that exists in the `recommend` list.